# Using a List Summary Value for Dynamic Cube List Report

Tags: list, olap, cognos, summary

Within my Cognos 10.2 list report, I am using a Dynamic Cube as a source.  Based on the business requirments I am using a list rather than a crosstab to show specific OLAP data.

My issue is that I need to create a column that uses the value of a cell within the row divided by the total of all such values in that column...for the level in the row.

Ok so here is an example:

```
    Col1 Row1 = Red
    Col1 Row2 = Blue

    Col2 Row1 = 40
    Col2 Row2 = 50

    Col3 Row1 = .44
    Col3 Row2 = .55

Total for Col2 Rows 1&2 = 90
```

In the example above, Col1 is a hierarchy and so I am able to drill up/down thus changing the values of the columns to the right of it.

I am attempting to build Col3, which has the formula of Col2 / (Total(Col2)).  The challenge is to get the correct Total value based on the edge value of Col1.  So while the example shows a total of 90, if I were to drill down on 'Red', then the total would be different..and thus would impact the value of Col3.

I created a List Summary item for Col2, and attempted to use that within a calculated data item in the list..but what is happening is that the total is not summarizing for all values only for the row.  So instead of seeing .44 I am seeing 1..which is dividing itself by itself!

So...I believe the issue is that I need a way to summarize at each level of the hierarchy so that I can use that value in the calculation.  But I have not found a way as of yet...if anyone has any suggestions...i am listening :)

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your data, but it sounds like you're going to need to do some sort of `TOTAL [column] for [dimensional value]`

Comment: Yea...that is what I have been working with but to no avail. It seems I am contending with the left edge hiearchy. I just think i need to find a way to capture the constant summarized value.  I have used total(Col2 for report) and this gives a static value for all possible values in that column.

Comment: Are you looking to divide any given value by the total of it's parent's value?  If so, look into `ANCESTOR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit unclear whether you wanted to divide by the total amount for the the root of your hierarchy which doesn't change, or by the current members of the hierarchy on the edge which change as you drill-down. I was able to do both.

**Current Edge Members**

```
[Col2]/aggregate([Col2] within set [Col1])
```

**Root Members**

```
[Col2]/aggregate([Col2] within set {Full reference to the root level of the hierarchy})
```

Replace the text in braces with the full reference to the root level of your hierarchy from the model.